# Is it possible to create a field that maps a string to another?

Tags: apex, map, language, text

A little more of context:

Let's suppose you are creating some customizations, and your user wants to be able to do something based on the language defined in the Account object (using a custom picklist field).

In the picklist field I have, for example, the string "British English", but would like the system to map it to the string `en_UK`, to reference it in the code.

Is there a way to do this without having to edit apex manually in Salesforce?

This would be particularly useful when you want to send e-mail templates based on the user language (without using VisualForce templates, that I know to use the parameter `language="lang_code"`).

Comment: Have you tried using a formula field with a case statement?

Comment: No. I suppose that is one way, but it still isn't user-friendly enough, in my opinion. Thanks for reminding me of that option.

Comment: User friendly for the admin, or user friendly for the end user?

Comment: Formula Field sounds ideal, but I suppose you could also use Picklists and Field Dependencies? Still, Formula Fields would be much better approach.

Comment: @NickCook in my case, the administrator is the user.

Comment: If the number of languages was small, I would do this with a custom setting that was a JSON array of objects and simply deserialize it in the apex code (total json string must be <= 255); if the list of languages was large, I'd move to a custom configuration object with a text area long field containing the json array of objects.